# Get non-zero value from current or previous row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working in Excel. 
Suppose I have two columns. In first column, there are some zero and some non-zero values. The second column is blank.

If there is a non zero value in a cell of first column, the same value should be written in the next column. But if the value is a zero, then the previous non zero value in the first column should be written in the second column. So, in the end, the second column gets filled with all non zero values.

Could you help me to write the formula?

Comment: What should be done if the first value is zero?

Comment: The cell should be left blank if the very first value is zero

Comment: Then I believe macl's solution below should work for you, provided you change the formula for the topmost cell from `=if(A1=0;0;A1)` to `=if(A1=0;"";A1)`.

Comment: Thanks, @eirikdaude, I updated the spreadsheet to reflect this.

Comment: @macl No problem, it's not like it was a huge change to your code. However, it seems that you should update your answer to include the formulas and maybe some explanation of what you are doing to avoid getting your answer deleted for just containing a link to an external site.

Comment: Wow, thanks again, didn't know an explanation was required.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want. Please take a look:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/183LFCPGfBnA0IEs4LKxk7iOgayxIFdCDaFZjFcwSU3M/edit?usp=sharing

Basically, First cell in second column, will check for zero in the first cell in first column:

```
=if(A1=0;"";A1)
```

Subsequent cells from second column will display the value of the cell above if the adjacent cell in the first column is zero:

```
=if(A2=0;B1;A2)
```

From there, is just formula extension down by the column.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your spreadsheet like this:

```
A1="Title"
A2=123
A3=0
A4=321
```

You could use this formula in cell B2, and copy it down:

```
B2=IF(A2=0, OFFSET(B2,-1,-1,1,1), A2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data/values start in the first column, here is an if statement that will handle it for you.

`=IF(A2>0,A2,B1)`

Comment: This will not work if you have two or more consecutive zeros in the first column

Comment: Here is a modification that takes into account consecutive zeros: =IF(A2>0,A2,B1)